# Get ADF Linked Service Username from Azure SQL Vault

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I have a connection string stored in Key Vault and I'm able to grab the secret and use it in my linked service. I have passed the username into the connection string:

```
Integrated Security=True;Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;UID=username
```

However in the ADF linked service I'm still being prompted for a username and can't seem to get around this.

Is there a way around it? I need to populate the username field in order to test the connection and save

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the Azure Key vault to get the Windows authentication username and use it in SQL linked service Azure Data factory. Currently you can only get the password using AKV.

This could be feature request. I would recommend you to please log a feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community

Instead you can parametrize the username if needed.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties) it is not clear to me that the username is a required property. After reading [the Varigence docs on Linked Services for SQL Server](https://docs.varigence.com/BimlFlex/metadata-editors/linked-service-adf-sql-server#user-name) it was clear to me that the username is a required property if you choose to connect with Windows Authentication.

> User Name will be used by the Linked Service form for SQL
> Authentication or Windows Authentication with the SQL Server Linked
> Service. User Name is required - except when using SQL Authentication
> with Azure Key Vault in place of a manually entering a Connection
> String.